# Roll up from contract to Account using Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, roll-up-summary

I have a requirement in which I need to roll up (SUM) a field called Score from Contract to Account. Account & Contract object shares lookup. I know very well this can be achieved using trigger but the loop hole is I need to accomplish it using THE PROCESS BUILDER. Is it possible in any way?

Comment: Incrementing a number field on Account every time a Contract is created is easy with process builder. The catch is deletion of a Contract, since you cannot start a process from a delete action. Are Contracts ever deleted in your situation?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you have to create sObject variable in process builder for your SUM value and  loop records. Please check this link:

http://www.salesforceweek.ly/2015/02/how-to-create-roll-up-summaries-using-flow.html